# WooCommerce Call a method written in functions.php through AJAX

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have defined a method in the functions.php as below:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', $product, 2);
function return_custom_price($price, $product) {  
  return 'something';
}
```

Also, created a select box by using this code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 

'wps_add_select_checkout_field');
function wps_add_select_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    //echo '<h2>'.__('Select Price').'</h2>';
    woocommerce_form_field( 'selectCountry', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array( 'wps-drop' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Select Price' ),
        'options'       => array(
            'AU'        => __( 'AU', 'wps' ),
            'NZ'    => __( 'NZ', 'wps' ),
            'OTHER' => __( 'IE', 'wps' ),
            'UK'    => __( 'GB', 'wps' )
        )
 ),
    $checkout->get_value( 'daypart' ));
}
```

I have enqueued the JS as like below:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueueforAjax' );
function my_enqueueforAjax() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_price', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/selectCountry.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_localize_script('custom_price', 'ajax_var', array(
     'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
     'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajaxnonce')
     ));
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_return_custom_price', 'return_custom_price' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_return_custom_price', 'return_custom_price' );
```

I wrote the following Jquery codes in the selectCountry.js file:

```
var jExample = jQuery.noConflict();
jExample( document ).ready(function() {
    jExample('#selectCountry').on('change', function() {
        var value = jExample('#selectCountry').val();

jExample.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: ajax_var.url,   
            data: "action=return_custom_price&nonce="+ajax_var.nonce+"&country="+value,  
            success: function(response){
                 // Do your stuff here once ajax response is returned
            console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When I change the selectbox values, the jquery function is not calling. How can I solve this issue? Is there any mistake? Your suggestions are invited.

Comment: Any errors in browser console? And write data as JSON: 
`{action: "return_custom_price", nonce: ajax_var.nonce, country: value}`

Comment: @MaximSarandi - No Console error / value I see

Comment: @MaximSarandi - Sorry for the above comment, I see the error in the console : ajax_var is not defined